# How to link to an entry in a Markdown field in the CMS

Tags: wysiwyg, link, markdown

I want to do something that's perhaps connected to the id so that if the title/slug updates, then I don't have to hunt anything down in entries across the CMS.

Something like this maybe?
`[Link to an entry](/section#entry:10725)`

Comment: For example, highlight text in a rich text area and link to an entry?

Comment: Yeah, how do I get the url like that based on an id?

Comment: I don't think I quite follow. If you highlight text (redactor for example) Craft will convert that for you. Just highlight the text and chose link -> entry Which will look something like this in the markup: `http://mysite.com/#entry:2`

You can change the `#entry:2` title, slug - whatever and everything will still work since Craft is linking to the entry. It doesn't care what you call it.

Comment: The field isn't Rich Text; it's just plain text, and the template code uses the `|markdown` filter.  I know how to make a link in markdown `[text](url)` but I'm wondering how to fill in the url dynamically based on id.  `http://mysite.com/#entry:2` doesn't work because it prints exactly that string out as the url.  I want `#entry:2` to convert into the uri for that entry on output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out how to do this. It was vexing me!

Anyway, Craft is awesome and has provided support for [Reference Tags](https://craftcms.com/docs/reference-tags).

Write your Markdown like this:

```
[link text]({entry:20})
```

Here's the Twig:

```
{{ entry.markdown|parseRefs|markdown }}
```

Reference Tags support more than just entries, but this was the bit that I needed.

Comment: Wow! Excellent answer @plaintxt! This works, and I learned something new about Craft. Well done!

Comment: Also, it's pretty cool that you can get all kinds of information about an entry using Reference Tags. I used this yesterday:

[{entry:40:title}]({entry:40})

Which resolves to an <a> tag populated with the entry's title and url.